# Nodejs Body parser taking long

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, http-post, body-parser

What's happening is: Sometimes one of my POST API is taking huge amount of time

So what I checked is:

- Is there any load on the system at that time - NO
- Are my thread blocked - NO
- Is payload coming is too large - NO ( around 20KB or 100KB max )

Its taking time in BODY PARSER ( not able to reach my application layer code only
JSON PARSER only taking this much amount of time )

[Taking 41 seconds only for json parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M93dy.png)

Comment: Checked all post related to this.
Got no reply as such

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I think people will need code to see whats going on. Maybe try a JsFiddle to reproduce the issue if possible or write a small code snippet of what you think is the issue.